# Entity Framework stored column mapping issue with DTO

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm retrieving columns from database using a stored procedure and binding values into my DTO class through EF code first approach.

I'm facing issue to get the values for `ReferenceNumber`, `BookingNumber` properties. I'm getting empty values for these properties.

Executing stored procedure through EF code first approach:

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@Id", 1); 
var stocks = await context.Database.SqlQuery<Stock>("dbo.[GetStocks @Id", param1).ToListAsync();
```

Stored procedure to get stock list:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStocks]  
    (@id INTEGER)  
AS    
BEGIN  
    SELECT ID, name, RefNo, BookingNo 
    FROM dbo.Stock
END
```

DTO class to get the values

```
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    using System;

    public partial class Stock
    {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
       public string BookingNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

{
    "ID" : "1" ,
    "Name":"ABC",
    "ReferenceNumber":"",
    "BookingNumber":""
}

Do we any option to get these values?

Comment: You’re missing a ‘]’.

Comment: Your select statement does not return any column with the name ReferenceNumber or BookingNumber. Property names in the objects must match those in data reader for this to work. You can either rename the database columns to match exact properties names on your model or rename property names on your model to match database colunm names

Comment: What is real issue?  Why is there a problem if values are empty?

Comment: @codein is correct.

Comment: @codein Do we have any option to mention db column name explicitly in C# DTO class using any attribute?

Comment: There is a ColumnName Attribute in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation which specifies the column the property should be mapped to

Comment: @codein Could please provide example for this?

Comment: using  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace example
{

class Sample{

[Column("FirstName")]
string Name {get;set;} 
}
}

Comment: @codein, I checked in my code by using Column attribute in my DTO class. Its not working in calling above SP. Could help me. `namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    using System;

    public partial class Stock
    {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       
       [Column("RefNo",TypeName = "varchar")]
       public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

       public string BookingNumber { get; set; }
    }
}`

Comment: Is there something that restricts you from renaming property names in your DTO to match column names in your database? if the answer to this is yes and you are also restricted from modify the stored procedure as advised in the answer below, you may use SQLCommand to execute the SP and read result from DataReader yourself.

Comment: Finally I found it. We can't use this column attribute between SP columns and DTO . We can use this mapping only between table Columns and DTO.. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select statement does not return any column with the name ReferenceNumber or BookingNumber. Property names in the objects must match those in data reader for this to work. You can either rename the database columns to match exact properties names on your model or rename property names on your model to match database column names.

Alternatively,  you can rewrite your SP as below:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStocks]  
(  
  (@id INTEGER
  )  
  AS    
 BEGIN  
  SELECT ID, name, RefNo as 'ReferenceNumber ', BookingNo as 'BookingNumber ' from
  FROM dbo.Stock where id =@id
 END
```

Since you are retrieving  a single entity from db based on id paramter, there is no need to call ToList extension method. Use .SingleOrDefaultAsync()

Comment: Do we have any option to mention db column name explicitly in C# DTO class using any attribute?